Analytic continuation of $\mathcal{M}$ in Peskin and Schroeder QFT book
In Peskin and Schroeder QFT book on page 232 they define $\mathcal{M}(s)$, the $S$-matrix element, to be defined by the Feynman rules, where $s=E^2_{cm}$ can have complex values.
Let $s_0$ be the threshold for producing multiparticle states. It is then claimed that because $\mathcal{M}(s)$ is analytic when $s < s_0$ and $s$ is real, it can be analytically continued to the whole complex plane.
My questions are:

Don't we need a function to be defined on an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ to have analytically continuation?
Later they claimed that $\mathcal{M}(s)$ has a branch cut at $s > s_0$, how could it be true if it is analytic function?


I would recommend complex-plotting $\mathcal{M}(s)$ with the first pole at $m^2$ (which should be a simple pole on the real axis), and then draw the branch cut at $s_0$ which for $n$-point scattering usually goes as $s\geq (nm)^2$ (which in this case is just $s_0$). Now, draw the contour in the UHP and deform is such that you pick up the entire UHP plus the simple pole (first mass state) and the branch cut (all possible multi-particle states in the theory). You can then argue that the UHP contour vanishes (as it should to ensure causality), while you just get the first mass state plus BC.
